# How to replace a particular string from a given string in java?

Tags: java, string

I have a string name and an another string chapterName(contains name + some integer).How can i replace name from the chapterName which leaves only integer??

```
String name = "name";
String chapterName = "name 123";
```

I want chapterName = 123.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It is nice to see any effort you put forth. If so, post the code you used to solve this and what results you got vs. what you expected.

Comment: If its always the same eg, "Some_1_Word_String numbers", then use split(" ") and take the 2nd part

Answer (score 2):

```
replace(String text, String searchString, String replacement)
```

Use this method of string utils.

Comment: Why use an extra dependency to String Utils if you have `replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` on `String` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the content of `name` variable from the variable `chapterName`, you could just use replace as shown below.

`System.out.println(chapterName.replace(name, ""));`

But if you just want to remove any non-integer characters from the string you could do it with the following regex.

`System.out.println(chapterName.replaceAll("\\D+", ""));`

Answer (score -1):

Using a regular expression. Search for an arbitrary number of non-digit characters and replace them with an empty string.

Comment: but name can also contains some integer.

Comment: But you know that between the name and the digits is a whitespace and that within those digits there is no whitespace? So either search backward for the digits or simply split the chapterName with the .split method and take the last entry of the array.